# Show body content with popup in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$large_image    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');

$output .= '<a class="overlay" rel="shadowbox" href="'.$large_image[0].'">';
```

It's OK, working fine.

But I want, show post's body in popup. I tried like this but not working.

```
   $content     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( body($post->ID));
```

Whats the problem? How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: I think, your problem was solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, maybe because `body` isn't a function in WP or php, or because you're trying to use [a function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) that return image source (come on the function name tell you by itself what it does) and hope it'll return (by magic) post content?

Here is how you get the content from a post, [within the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

And if you're outside the loop, you can do:

```
$content = $post->post_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can consider [alligator popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/alligator-popup/)
check how it works, you will get some idea.